# Having trouble with JOptionPane being painted onto my JPanel

Tags: java, jpanel, joptionpane

I am making a hangman game and am having trouble with my JOptionPane in my program. Anytime it comes up, it gets painted onto the JPanel. I'm not really sure what the issue is but any help is appreciated. [Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSx3M.png)

Hangman Class

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Hangman
{
protected JFrame frame=new JFrame("Hangman");
private HangmanPanel panel;
private final int GAMEWIDTH=800, GAMEHEIGHT=600;
protected WordHandler wh;
private Timer timer;
private boolean reset = true;
private boolean showAnswer = false;
private int readyToQuit=1;
public Hangman(){
    try {
        wh = new WordHandler("dictionary.txt");
    } 
    catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe) { 
        System.out.println(fnfe.getMessage());
    } 
}

public int getReadyToQuit(){
    return readyToQuit;
}

public void run(){
    frame.setSize(GAMEWIDTH, GAMEHEIGHT); frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
    frame.setVisible(true); frame.setResizable(false); 
    //frame.addKeyListener(tetris);
    //frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){  });
    Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    frame.setLocation(dim.width/2-frame.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-frame.getSize().height/2);
    panel=new HangmanPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel); 
    frame.getContentPane().validate(); 
    frame.getContentPane().repaint();
    frame.addKeyListener(panel);
    frame.pack();
    timer=new Timer(1000/60,new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {update();}});
    timer.start();
}

public void addLetter(String letter)
{
    if(wh.guess(letter))
    {
        panel.repaint();
    }
}

public void update()
{
    panel.repaint();

}

public int drawQuitFrame(){
    String[] options = new String[] {"Play Again", "Quit"}; int i=-1;
    while(i<0) 
        i=JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Do you want to play again?","GAME OVER",  JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);

    if(i==0)
        return 0;
    else{
        return 1;
    }
}   

public void drawResetFrame(){
    String[] options = new String[] {"Yes", "No"};
    int i=-1;
    while(i<0)
    {
        i=JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Do you want to reset the game?","RESET",  JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
    }
    switch(i){
        case 0: wh.resetSolution(); reset = true; showAnswer = false; break;
        default:  break;
    }
    timer.start();
}

public void drawCloseFrame(){
    String[] options = new String[] {"Yes", "No"}; int i=-1;
    while(i<0) 
        i=JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Do you want to return to the menu?","Quit?",  JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
    readyToQuit=i;
}   

public void resetGame(){
    wh.resetSolution(); reset = true; showAnswer = false; 
}

public class HangmanPanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener
{
    public HangmanPanel(){
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(GAMEWIDTH,GAMEHEIGHT));
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        if(reset)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillRect(0,0,GAMEWIDTH,GAMEHEIGHT);
            reset = false;
        }
        g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 15));
        g.drawString("Press esc to quit",GAMEWIDTH-160,GAMEHEIGHT-30);
        g.drawString("Press enter to restart",GAMEWIDTH-160,GAMEHEIGHT-10);
        if(!showAnswer)
        {
            g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 50));
            for(int i = 0; i < wh.getCurrGuess().length(); i++)
            {
                g.drawString(wh.getCurrGuess().substring(i,i+1),((i*75)+50),500);
                g.drawString("__",((i*75)+40),510);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 50));
            for(int i = 0; i < wh.getCurrGuess().length(); i++)
            {
                g.drawString(wh.getSolution().substring(i,i+1),((i*75)+50),500);
                g.drawString("__",((i*75)+40),510);
            }
        }
        g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 30));
        g.drawString("Guessed Letters",533,40);
        for(int i = 0; i < wh.getGuessedLetters().size(); i++)
        {
            g.drawString(wh.getGuessedLetters().get(i),(((i%5)*50)+540),(((i/5)*50)+100));
        }
        g.fillRect(40,340,225,20);
        g.fillRect(140,30,20,310);
        g.fillRect(140,30,200,20);
        g.fillRect(340,30,20,40);
        if(wh.getRemainingGuesses() == 5)
        {
            g.fillOval(320,65,60,60);
        }
        else if(wh.getRemainingGuesses() == 4)
        {
            g.fillOval(320,65,60,60);
            g.fillRect(340,120,20,110);
        }
        else if(wh.getRemainingGuesses() == 3)
        {
            g.fillOval(320,65,60,60);
            g.fillRect(340,120,20,110);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(20));
            g2.drawLine(355,230,410,275);
        }
        else if(wh.getRemainingGuesses() == 2)
        {
            g.fillOval(320,65,60,60);
            g.fillRect(340,120,20,110);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(20));
            g2.drawLine(355,230,410,275);
            g2.drawLine(345,230,290,275);
        }
        else if(wh.getRemainingGuesses() == 1)
        {
            g.fillOval(320,65,60,60);
            g.fillRect(340,120,20,110);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(20));
            g2.drawLine(355,230,410,275);
            g2.drawLine(345,230,290,275);
            g2.drawLine(345,170,290,125);
        }
        else if(wh.getRemainingGuesses() == 0)
        {
            g.fillOval(320,65,60,60);
            g.fillRect(340,120,20,110);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(20));
            g2.drawLine(355,230,410,275);
            g2.drawLine(345,230,290,275);
            g2.drawLine(345,170,290,125);
            g2.drawLine(355,170,410,125);
        }
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_A){addLetter("A");}
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_B){addLetter("B");}
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_C){addLetter("C");}
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_D){addLetter("D");}
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_E){addLetter("E");}
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_F){addLetter("F");}
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_G){addLetter("G");}
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_H){addLetter("H");}
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_I){addLetter("I");}
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_J){addLetter("J");}
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_K){addLetter("K");}
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_L){addLetter("L");}
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_M){addLetter("M");}
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_N){addLetter("N");}
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_O){addLetter("O");}
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_P){addLetter("P");}
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_Q){addLetter("Q");}
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_R){addLetter("R");}
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_S){addLetter("S");}
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_T){addLetter("T");}
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_U){addLetter("U");}
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_V){addLetter("V");}
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_W){addLetter("W");}
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_X){addLetter("X");}
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_Y){addLetter("Y");}
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_Z){addLetter("Z");}
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE){
            timer.stop();
            drawCloseFrame();
            if(readyToQuit==1)
                timer.start();
        }
        else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
            timer.stop();
            drawResetFrame();
        }
    }
}
```

Word Handler Class

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class WordHandler
{
private ArrayList<String> words;
private int remainingGuesses;
private String solution;
private String currGuess;
private ArrayList<String> guessedLetters;

/**
 * Construct an EvilHangman object and initiailize all instance variables.
 * @param fileName the name of the file that contains the word list.
 * @throws FileNotFoundException when the fileName file does not exist.
 */
public WordHandler(String fileName)
throws FileNotFoundException
{
    inputWords(fileName);
    remainingGuesses = 6;
    int pos = (int)(Math.random()*words.size());
    solution = words.get(pos);
    //solution = "ANT";
    guessedLetters = new ArrayList<String>();
    updateCurrGuess();
}

public boolean guess(String letter)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < guessedLetters.size(); i++)
    {
        if(guessedLetters.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(letter))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    guessedLetters.add(letter);
    if(contains(letter))
    {
        updateCurrGuess();
    }
    else
    {
        remainingGuesses--;
    }
    return true;
}

public void updateCurrGuess()
{
    currGuess = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < solution.length(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < guessedLetters.size(); j++)
        {
            if(solution.substring(i,i+1).equalsIgnoreCase(guessedLetters.get(j)))
            {
                currGuess += guessedLetters.get(j);
                j = guessedLetters.size();
            }
        }
        if(currGuess.length() <= i)
        {
            currGuess += " ";
        }
    }
}

public boolean contains(String letter)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < solution.length(); i++)
    {
        if(solution.substring(i,i+1).equalsIgnoreCase(letter))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public String getCurrGuess()
{
    return currGuess;
}

public String getSolution()
{
    return solution;
}

public ArrayList<String> getGuessedLetters()
{
    return guessedLetters;
}

public int getRemainingGuesses()
{
    return remainingGuesses;
}

public void resetSolution()
{
    int pos = (int)(Math.random()*words.size());
    solution = words.get(pos);
    remainingGuesses = 6;
    guessedLetters.clear();
    updateCurrGuess();
}

public boolean gameOver()
{
    return remainingGuesses == 0 || currGuess.equalsIgnoreCase(solution);
}

////////// PRIVATE HELPER METHODS //////////
/**
 * Helper method for the constructor:
 * Inputs the word length from the user, reads in the words from
 * the fileName file, and initializes the words instance variable
 * with the words of the correct length.  This method loops until
 * a valid word length is entered.
 * @param fineName the name of the file that contains the word list.
 * @throws FileNotFoundException when the fileName file does not exist.
 */
private void inputWords(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    words = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (words.size() == 0)
    {
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        while (file.hasNext())
        {
            String word = file.next();
            if(word.length() < 11)
            {
                words.add(word);
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Helper method for playGame:
 * Inputs a one-letter string from the user.
 * Loops until the string is a one-character character in the range
 * a-z or A-Z.
 * @return the single-letter string converted to upper-case.
 */
private String inputLetter()
{
    //         String letter = null;
    //         while (letter == null)
    //         {
    //             System.out.print("Next letter? ");
    //             letter = scanner.next().toUpperCase();
    // 
    //             if (letter.length() != 1 ||
    //             "A".compareTo(letter) > 0 ||
    //             "Z".compareTo(letter) < 0)
    //             {
    //                 letter = null;
    //                 System.out.println("Invalid input!");
    //             }
    //         }
    //         return letter;
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Never seen this before so I upvoted to get it more attention. However, it would be easier for us to help if you provided a more minimal example. Start removing parts of your program that are not needed to reproduce the problem until you have the smallest possible amount of code that will still reproduce it. That will help us (and you) find the cause. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The first line of code in a `paintComponent` method must always be `super.paintComponent(g);`.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/ and http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html .